# Cannot connect to internet from VIRTUALBOX

Tags: virtualbox, internet

From my virtualbox device I cannot connect to internet.

`ping www.google.com` works well. But when I open mozilla and try connect to internet, it is unsuccessful. In virtualbox settings in Windows I use NAT network adapter. What I am doing wrong? In ububtu I didn`t make any changes, it is a clean install.

Host OS: Windows7

Guest OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try to change network adapter to Bridge.

Comment: I already tried, it doesn`t help.

Comment: Please add the complete output of `ping`. Have you tried to run `wget www.google.com`? What’s the output? If the problem is no more relevant, please close or delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a Network NAT in VirtualBox and then change the Network settings of your VirtualMachine (Ubuntu 16.04) to the Network NAT you crated.

If that doesn't work, try to swap again to NAT and reboot your virtual machine. Once you are in Ubuntu, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and type `sudo service networking  restart`

Comment: I already configured NAT interface in VirtualBox and checked the interface config in Linux which all looked good. `service networking restart` was all I then needed and resolved the issue for me.